# Disable translations for specific managed package

Tags: managed-package, translation

I have a managed package installed in my environment which used to be only available in English. Most of our users have set their Salesforce language to Dutch, but are used to having all of the stuff from the managed package in English.

After a recent update of the package a Dutch translation was included, but the translations themselves are horrible. I want my users to just keep using English for the managed package, while having their Salesforce language set to Dutch.

Is there any way to disable the Dutch translations that came with the update? I have only updated the app in a sandbox, so if there's any way to exclude the translations when installing the update on production, that could also work.

Comment: Once I had a weird issue -- I have installed a package on an org with disabled translation workbench, and translations were not installed even after I enabled it after that. So there were no translations for fields/labels with such an installation

Comment: Assuming the managed package developer used standard Salesforce localization features such as custom labels, schema object and field labelling etc. you should be able to provide your own translations, overriding the managed package, using the Translation Workbench on your org.

Comment: Thanks @kurunve that's worth a try, to disable the translation workbench during update. and PhilW, they did use all of the standard stuff, so that could be an option. That would take a lot of time though, so a quicker solution would be preferable.